# Dynamically adding sets of radio inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, radio-group

So I have dynamic form that I create and there could be multiple sets of radio inputs they all do have the same name Release[] but I do not know how to group the properly now if you will add 4 sets of those radio inputs you will be only able to select 1 from all of them

```
$('a#AddChampion').on('click', function () {
  $('div#ChampionInput').append(
    '<input type="radio" name="Release[]" value="New">New\
    <input type="radio" name="Release[]" value="Rework">Rework\
    <input type="radio" name="Release[]" value="None" checked>None\
  ');
});
```

Comment: Your code seems fine. Take a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pqcyysa8/). I just added `'\ ` after `append(`, but I assume you did it well in your original code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you intend to use the same name only one output can be obtained. If you want to collect them separately you will have to use separate names.

E.g.
For two groups of ReleaseGrp1 and ReleaseGrp2

```
                 <input type="radio" name="ReleaseGrp1" value="New">New
                 <input type="radio" name="ReleaseGrp1" value="Rework">Rework
                 <input type="radio" name="ReleaseGrp1" value="None" checked>None

                     <input type="radio" name="ReleaseGrp2" value="New">New
                     <input type="radio" name="ReleaseGrp2" value="Rework">Rework
                     <input type="radio" name="ReleaseGrp2" value="None" checked>None
```

Comment: is there any easier way to group them with html array [] like so it would be easier to obtain data after sending form

Comment: No direct way with radio type input. But If you could add some hidden elements with name Release[] and populate them with selected radio options just before submitting the form, it could work. Just a suggestion.